# Standard library not resolved in Eclipse Juno

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am building a Makefile project in Eclipse Juno, and I have it set up so it compiles and debugs (it's using CMake, so I'm not using the internal tools). However, Eclipse obviously hasn't been informed of the right headers, as in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{    
  cout << "Hello world << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the include "iostream" and symbols "std", "cout" and "endl" are all unresolved.

How should I make Eclipse aware of these so it will stop underlining everything in red and spamming with errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by specifying the following environmental variables in Project->Properties->C++ Build->Environment.

- LANG=en_US
- LC_ALL=en_US

Apparently they are needed for the auto-discovery tools to work out where the includes live.

Answer gleaned from [this Eclipse forum thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/275956/).